# Why are visualizing mnemonics usually wacky?

Tags: visualization, mnemonic

Why are mnemonic visualization techniques often characterized by their eccentricity? It has been suggested to me that when employing these methods, such as the Major System, I should conjure up images and weave narratives that are as outlandish and nonsensical as conceivable. Could the rationale behind this advice be rooted in the propensity of our brains to retain memories of events that deviate from the ordinary?

Comment: The Internet has surprisingly little to say about this beyond listicles of memory tips.